# using window.store to make the redux store global is a good idea or not?

Tags: reactjs, redux

When using redux, after creating store, I think we could make it global by 
set it to window.store = store1 for example.

If I could use this, I could freely subscribe or dispatch to the store in any component. My question is why I need to use react-redux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That way you can only read the data on mounted once. For every changes after that, you need a way to trigger your component to re-render (i.e. update either props or state), thus the need for redux selectors.

Comment: I could subscribe to store?

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing a similar need for `window.store`.  There are benefits like being able to say `window.store.getState()` while debugging, it means you can call action functions that have several dispatches without running them thru mapDispatchToProps and "dispatching" things that aren't action creators.  Hard to know if this is a a good idea or a bad one, but it has definitely made a good bit of the code a lot easier to read.